# Objective-C : Sending Hidden Email

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a question regarding the MFMailComposeViewController in iOS programming.  I am fairly new to the language, and my goal is to send a hidden email through the app I am creating.  I would like for an email to be sent without the user having to press the send button that appears when an email dialog pops up.  How can I have an email sent without a dialog showing up at all?

Below is my code:

```
    //Sending Mail
    -(IBAction)sendemail:(id)sender
    {
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {
            MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mail setSubject:@"Sample Subject"];
            [mail setMessageBody:@"Here is some main text in the email!" isHTML:NO];
            [mail setToRecipients:@[@"test@example.com"]];

            [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"This device cannot send email");
        }
    }

    - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
    {
        switch (result) {
            case MFMailComposeResultSent:
                NSLog(@"You sent the email.");
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
                NSLog(@"You saved a draft of this email");
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
                NSLog(@"You cancelled sending this email.");
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
                NSLog(@"Mail failed:  An error occurred when trying to compose this email");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"An error occurred when trying to compose this email");
                break;
        }

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who replies.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can't do this ( for good reason) with MFMailComposeViewController. You can use some other email/message service in your app, but you won't be able to send using the user's credentials - unless they tell your their email address and you use that as the "from"

Comment: Thank you for your response, but if I can't use the MFMailComposeViewController, then what can I use to accomplish this?  Is there any other way to send an email without a dialogue box appearing?

Comment: Understand why this is not allowed.  Apple does not want there to be a possibility that you can send an email that is "from" the user and which the user hasn't seen and approved of.

Comment: I understand.  Do you know of any other solution that I could find? (Internet resource, YouTube video...)

Comment: You haven't yet described a problem.

Comment: What do you mean?  I stated clearly in my description that I was looking for a way to send an email without the use of a dialogue box.  My problem is that the code I posted doesn't accomplish what I'm looking for it to do.

Answer (score 3):

> MFMailComposeViewController .... my goal is to send a hidden email

Those goals are contradictory. If you want to send an email secretly from the user, then *don't* use MFMailComposeViewController. You'd have to teach your app SMTP and send the email yourself using low-level networking. (And if Apple finds out you're doing this, they will, I hope, yank your app right off the store.)

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but then how do many other app developers do what I'm trying to accomplish?  There has to be some other 'easier' solution.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the app sending an email *per se* as long as it is coming from "someapp@appdeveloper.com" not "myemail@mydomain.com" without my knowledge/permission.  You can use a library such as MailCore - http://libmailcore.com rather than having to start from the ground up with an SMTP client

Comment: Thank you.  In my specific app, the goal is anonymity.  I would prefer the use of no dialogue.  Is there a way for me to change the code I have pasted above to meet your suggestion?

Comment: @Paulw11 There may not be an actual problem as far as Apple is concerned, but I'm saying I think there should be. I personally don't want an app that I use secretly sending emails under any name.

Comment: @user3870884 You're asking me? No, there's no way to simply "change the code". Read what I said! And I also said I don't _want_ you to have anonymity. Not only can you not do what you want to do the way you're doing it, I want to _discourage_ you from doing what you want to do.

Comment: I don't see it as a problem.

Comment: @matt what is the difference between sending an email and using an analytics tracking service or logging activity in a database somewhere - SMTP is just a different (and probably less effective) protocol.  For me it comes down to the content of the message rather than the transport - in this case we don't know the intended content so it could be innocent or pure evil (tm)

Comment: @user3870884 no, you cannot do this with the code you have posted.  You will need to use some other technique such as SMTP library or a web service as suggested in the other answer.  Depending on what you are actually trying to do, an email may not be the best approach anyway

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks.  I'm not a very advance 'objective-c' programmer.  Do you know of a place for me to learn how to do this?

Comment: libmailcore has sample code right on their front page.  The other answer shows how to do it with Mailgun.  The only way to do it without using a 3rd party library is to implement an SMTP client at the socket level - very advanced and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will not allow you to hide `MFMailComposeViewController`. You'll need to use a web service to send the email.

Use an `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` to send a request to a web server which accepts a payload of JSON data that represents the email you want to send. The web server will then parse the data, do any necessary validation and processing, then either send the email itself or interact with a third-party email service. You can also try to cut out the middle-man server and interact directly with the third-party email service directly from the app however there may be some challenges to this approach, namely the security of your API token being baked into the app itself may expose your third-party account to abuse.

Sample code from [Mailgun Objective-C SDK](https://github.com/rackerlabs/objc-mailgun):

```
Mailgun *mailgun = [Mailgun clientWithDomain:@"samples.mailgun.org" apiKey:@"key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0"];
[mailgun sendMessageTo:@"Jay Baird <jay.baird@rackspace.com>" 
                   from:@"Excited User <someone@sample.org>" 
                subject:@"Mailgun is awesome!" 
                   body:@"A unicode snowman for you! ☃"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Is there a place I could find out how to do this?  I haven't learned material this advanced.  :)

Comment: Get a Mailgun (by Rackspace) account and try out their iOS Objective-C SDK: https://github.com/rackerlabs/objc-mailgun

Comment: Thank you!  Are there any built in API's that could help me solve my issue?  I would prefer to stay away from 3rd party downloads.

Comment: As for built in APIs - No. Only for making network requests like `NSURLRequest`, nothing specifically for email.

Comment: I see.  Is there any documentation on how to use the Mailgun?  The github was unclear...